# Display sina weibo public_timeline

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, weibo

I want to display my lastest sina weibo on my personal blog with my own css style using the statuses/public_timeline api.  The expected outcome should be simular to twitter widget in the footer of http://themes.pixelwars.org/responsy/.   I have no idea of how to handle the json response by javascript.  Any tutorial, example or plugin to doing this weibo widget?

Since I am host my blog on GitHub page, the solution should be static, i.e. javascript.

P.S.: I checked out the [plugin](http://app.weibo.com/tool?topnav=1&wvr=5) from sina weibo.  CSS style can't apply on cross domain.  Thus, it can't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you solve this? A have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try Weibo API doc (english) : [Weibo API](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3_V2/en).
Warning, the last update was in 2012 but the chinese update is from 2017.
You must get an API key from Weibo which is not easy as everything is in Chinese.

*As workaround you can embed a Weibo widget from external providers such as [Dialogfeed Weibo Widget](https://www.dialogfeed.com/embed-weibo-feed-on-page-get-weibo-api-data-or-widget/)*